# Filter and to stay only rows with the same index

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have two data frame: `X_oos_top_10` and `y_oos_top_10`. I need to filter them by `X_oos_top_10["comm"] == 1`.

I do it for one:

```
X_oos_top_10_comm1 = X_oos_top_10[X_oos_top_10["comm"] == 1]
```

But for another I have the problem: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

```
y_oos_top_10_comm1 = y_oos_top_10[X_oos_top_10["comm"] == 1]
```

I haven't ideas how I can do it.

Comment: Please format as code blocks using back ticks

Comment: What you might be able to do is join the X and y together, filter them, then reseparate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, X and y have the same length, you can use indexing.

Setup a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
X_oos_top_10 = pd.DataFrame({'comm': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)})
y_oos_top_10 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

print(X_oos_top_10)

# Output:
   comm
0     5
1     6
2     2
3     6
4     1
5     6
6     1
7     4
8     5
9     8

print(y_oos_top_10)

# Output:
   A  B  C  D
0  2  9  1  6
1  9  8  5  4
2  1  6  7  6
3  6  3  6  5
4  2  6  8  3
5  2  6  6  5
6  4  4  3  5
7  6  3  7  5
8  2  8  8  7
9  4  9  1  4
```

**1st method**

```
idx = X_oos_top_10[X_oos_top_10["comm"] == 1].index
out = y_oos_top_10.loc[idx]
print(out)

# Output:
   A  B  C  D
4  2  6  8  3
6  4  4  3  5
```

**2nd method**

```
Xy_oos_top_10 = X_oos_top_10.join(y_oos_top_10)
out = Xy_oos_top_10[Xy_oos_top_10['comm'] == 1]
print(out)

# Output:
   comm  A  B  C  D
4     1  2  6  8  3
6     1  4  4  3  5
```